# Salesforce for Outlook: How to create customized field in outlook to sync values to salesforce

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

Recently, we need to sync task/event between salesforce and outlook, so we used Salesforce for Outlook. About Salesforce for Outlook, there is a limit that the attendees in outlook can not be sync.
Click [this link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=outlookcrm_sync_events.htm&language=en_US) about limit.

How to create customized field in outlook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1, You need to create a customized form when you need to sync customized fields to salesforce.

[image]

## 2, select a form template. In this case, the event needs to be sync, so we choose the Appointment template.

[image]

## 3, select P.2 panel as picture shows, open Field Chooser panel and create new fields you want to sync, then drag them into panel, then click Publish Form As… button and save it to a folder.

[image]

## 4, go to the folder where new form was saved, right click and open Properties, as picture shows, select default form when new appointment is open, then save it.

[image]

## 5, Open Calendar folder, click New, select P.2 panel, fill customized fields, save the appointment and sync.

[image]